# INT_MAX does not behave right in an If-Statement

Tags: c, if-statement, int, max

My C-Program performs a "Turmrechnung"(A predefined number("init_num" gets multiplied with a predefined range of numbers(init_num*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9 in my case, defined by the variable "h"), and after that it is divided by those same numbers and the result should be the initial value of "init_num". My task is to integrate a way to stop the calculation if the value of init_num becomes larger than INT_MAX(from limits.h).
But the If-Statement is always true, even if it is not, in case of a larger initial value of "init_num", which results in values bigger than INT_MAX along the way of the calculation.

It only works if i replace "INT_MAX" with a smaller number than INT_MAX like 200000000 in my If-Statement. Why?

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int init_num = 1000000;
  int h = 9;

  for (int i = 2; i < h+1; ++i)
  {
    if (init_num * i < INT_MAX)
    {
      printf("%10i %s %i\n", init_num, "*", i);
      init_num *= i;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%s\n","An overflow has occurred!");
      break;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 2; i < h+1; ++i)
  {
    printf("%10i %s %i\n", init_num, ":", i);
    init_num /= i;
  }
  printf("%10i\n", init_num);


}
```

Comment: `INT_MAX` is the maximum value an `int` can have. Think about that.

Comment: You should do some reading on how overflows actually work. Hint: an _integer_ has a _sign_.

Comment: You should also consider why you use signed numbers, when your program has an obvious need of storing as large unsigned numbers as possible.

Comment: @Arc676 What is there to read about them, other than learning that signed integer overflow invokes undefined behavior? There is nothing of interest to know beyond that.

Comment: Int number multiple by int number is always int number! And int number is always smaller or equal like INT_MAX. In your case init_num * i < INT_MAX will be false only when init_num * i will be INT_MAX (othwrwise true).

Comment: @Arc676: If you need defined behaviour of integer overflow, you have to use `unsgned` integers (which would be better here anyway - but don't solve the actual problem).

Comment: @honza: As already stated by Lundin, signed integer overflwo is UB. And casting will not solve anything!

Comment: @Olaf: "*And casting will not solve anything!*" please elaborate. `if ((long) init_num * i < (long) INT_MAX)` should work pretty well, shouldn' it? Ok, to a certain extend ...

Comment: @alk: Not on most 32 bit systems with `MAX_LONG == MAX_INT` and e.g. Windows64 which also has 32 bit `long`. Similar for ILP64 systems (rare,but real). The correct approach would be to check before the multiplication.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes well, I obviously implied `long` is wider than `int` ... :-/ Your wording "*anything*" definitely isn't accurate.

Comment: @Olaf: "*The correct approach would be to check before the multiplication.*" This would would be the answer to accept then, yes ... ;-)

Comment: @alk: Welcome to comment ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (init_num * i < INT_MAX)
```

`INT_MAX` is the maximum value of `int` , therefore , this condition will never be *false* or in other words `0` (*except when it is equal to `INT_MAX`*).

If you want you can write your condition like this -

```
if (init_num < INT_MAX/i)
```

Comment: Change `false` to 0 pretty please? We are in C.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah , I will do that .

Comment: @Bathsheba even if `C` doesn't have the boolean data type, it still has the concept of boolean. A condition is either false or true.

Comment: @Bathsheba In C, "`false` which expands to the integer constant 0"  C11 §7.18 3  `false` is fine in C.

Comment: 1 or 0 according to the standard.

Comment: `Each of the operators < (less than), [...] shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int.` So while the result of the expression is `1` or `0` there is nothing wrong with saying the `condition will never be false`

Comment: @bolov: Who says C does not have a boolean datatype? Where have you been the last 16 years?

Comment: @ameyCU: `true` and `false` are the better (and correct) phrases. Even if you use the keywords (`false`), since C99.

Comment: @Olaf As you can see there was a discussion on this , therefore , I mentioned both . I also prefer `true` and `false` , and is more clear .

Comment: @ameyCU: I wanted to strenghten your back (provide backup for you) actually against the C90 followers :-)

Comment: @Olaf  Yes , surely I understand your point . I really appreciate that . Thank You !! :-)

Comment: Uh, but you should not have `false` as a keyword. In this aspect they are right: C comparison operators yield an integer result. Try `sizeof (1LL < 2LL)`, which should equal `sizeof(int)`. OTOH, it would be correct to write "equals `false`".

Comment: @Olaf Yes , but I did not suggested use of `false` particularly in expression but to describe what will be state of  the expression .

Comment: Yes, I know. But once you put a work into code-tags, it is suppose to be - well - code, not just natural language. To emphasise text, use either bold or italics (I'd use none her, though).

Comment: @Olaf I edited it . I think these things increase ambiguity :)

Comment: It's perfectly now;-) But I disagree; markup helps to make very clear what you actually mean. As given, I see that "false" has a specific meaning, but is not a keyword, while `0` is a value of the program (it is no token from the context). Nitpicky? Maybe, but **unambigously**.

Comment: @Olaf I would not call it _nitpicking_ but preference  :-)

Comment: Note: `sizeof (1LL < 2LL) ==  sizeof(int) == sizeof(false)` which may not equal `sizeof(bool)`.

Answer (score 2):

`init_num * i < INT_MAX` will only be 0 if `int_num * i` *is* `INT_MAX`. This is not particularly likely. Note that signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour in C, so do be particularly careful here.

You can rewrite your statement to `init_num < INT_MAX / i` in your particular case. Do note that integer division truncates though.

Comment: A boolena expression yields true or false. Either you use `0` as a token or "false" as logical term, but "0" is wrong as would `false` be. And you are wrong in general, as any overflow is UB, which may yield anything, including nasal daemons.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour. Concentrate on the "undefined" part and think about it. Briefly: avoid under all circumstances.

To avoid this, you can either use a devinitively wider type which is gauranteed to hold the result of the multiplication and then test:

```
// ensure the type we use for cast is large enough
_Static_assert(LLONG_MAX > INT_MAX, "LLONG too small.");

if ( (long long)init_num * i < (long long)INT_MAX )
```

This apparently does not work is you are already at the limit (i.e. use the largest data type). So you have to check in advance:

```
if ( init_num < (INT_MAX / i) ) {
    init_num *= i;
```

Although more time-consuming due to the extra division, this is in general the better approach, as it does not require a larger data type (where multiplication might be also more expensive).

Answer (score 0):

```
init_num * int
```

results in an `int` and though cannot grow beyond a maximum possible `int` (`INT_MAX`) by defintion.

So provide "room" for calculations "larger" than an `int` by replacing

```
if (init_num * i < INT_MAX)
```

with

```
if ((long) init_num * i < (long) INT_MAX)
```

The casting to `long` leads to a `long` result.

(The above approach assumes `long` being wider then `int`.)